# Changing text blink rate in assembler

Tags: assembly, x86

Is it possible to change the rate of blink?  The code I'm using for attribute is below.

```
mov ah, 09h
mov al, a
mov bl, b
mov cx, c
int 10h
```

Comment: If you saw my first post here before I edited it, sorry. I thought it's not working but I realized that I'm printing only spaces. And I changed the question to another question that I also need in my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't change the blink-rate.

On standard VGA adapters the blink attribute switches between on and off every 16 frames, so 60 frames/second you get around 1.8 blinks/second.

Most VGA adapters have extensions to the standardized VGA interface that may or may not allow to change the blink-rate. You could use this if your adapter has support for it and if you are able to get your hands on the chip documentation, but it will not work for other adapters and will not be portable.